# Finding project dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, ant

I'm working on a legacy app with several Java/Flex projects in Eclipse, including project P1, which uses Ant to compile (via mxmlc) property files into SWF files. (I don't know if Flex is relevant to this question.)

When I build P1, in Eclipse, via Ant/build.xml, it builds other projects: P2, P3, P4. I'd like to find these dependencies so I can remove them.

I've tried these, to no avail:

- Right-click on P1 -> Properties -> Builders
- Right-click on P1 -> Java Build Path -> Projects, Order and Export, etc
- Right-click on P1 -> Project References
- examined '.classpath' and '.project' in P1 folder

but there is nothing regarding P2, P3, P4.

As a sanity check, I've renamed build.xml and performed:

- Right-click on P1 -> Export -> Ant buildfiles

which generates a build.xml that clearly shows dependencies on P2, P3, P4.

Where else might I find the configuration? There must be another option?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that your P2,P3,P4 projects are having Linked files from P1. Then if you change these files or folders with the build in P1 it can trigger a build on P2,P3 or P4. Linked files could be created in OS level and in eclipse as well.

See http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-13.htm

Also check the builders of the P2,P3,P4 project builders, maybe you find something.

What kind of project facets do you have on P1,P2,P3,P4 projects?

Is it not possible, that the ant script of P1 simply touches the P2,P3,P4 with some path reference like "..\P2"?